# XLSX file not found Rails, file format not correct

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, import-from-excel

I'm working on a Rails application that will be reading into an XLSX file called properties. I constantly get the error that the file does not exist.

Here is my Wardrobe model that is reading into the spreadsheet:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'roo'
require 'json'

def
    ...
    find_properties
  self.save!
end

def find_properties
  binding.pry
  # xlsx = Roo::Spreadsheet.open('./Properties.xlsx')
  # xlsx = Roo::Excelx.new("./Properties.xlsx")
  book = Roo::Spreadsheet.open('./Properties.csv')
  book = Roo::CSV.new('Properties.csv')
  sheets = book.sheets
end
```

My Gemfile contains the 'roo' gem and two gems I gathered from similar questions

`gem 'roo'
gem 'rubyXL'
gem 'rubyzip'`

[image]
Above you can see I'm attempting to access the properties.xlsx file but it can not be found.

[image]
Here you can see the Properties.CSV file can be accessed but nothing is shown to be inside it

Currently these two files are in my "models" folder, I'm planning on placing them inside my public folder once I've solved this file access issue.

[image]

I've also just used RubyXL as another option, no bueno, it reads there is a file format error and it cannot be read as an XLSX file.

[image: RubyXL error]

[image]

From my research I've come across these questions: [unzipping problems xlsx](https://github.com/rubyzip/rubyzip/issues/105), [reading issues XLSX](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ruby-roo/MJLL9zbcvNo), [file format error](http://community.spiceworks.com/topic/331441-excel-cannot-open-file-file-xlsx-because-file-format-or-extension-is-not-valid)

Answer (score 3):

The correct path to your file is, assuming this models/concerns directory is within app:

```rb
File.join(Rails.root, 'app','models','concerns', 'properties.xslx')
```

Comment: Hi! Sorry if the picture could have used more context but I think it's under the main models folder, not the concerns subfolder. If I'm understanding you correctly I just put in this `s = File.join(Rails.root, 'app','models', 'properties.xslx')` which produces `"/Users/christinaleuci/Programming/Curate/Curate/app/models/properties.xslx"`. When I ran this as an Excelx I got `use Roo::Excelx.new to handle .xlsx spreadsheet files. This has .xslx
TypeError: /Users/christinaleuci/Programming/Curate/Curate/app/models/properties.xslx is not an Excel-xlsx file`.

Comment: You are correct, I saw the folder and just assumed it was open instead of looking more closely. You are getting the file now so at this point you just need to get the file in the correct format or use the correct Roo module. Just in case it needs to be mentioned: naming something "*.xlsx" does not automatically make it a valid Excel XSLX file.

Comment: Yes I'm aware, I've double and triple checked the file. It's an Open Office XML spreadsheet xlsx file. I've just converted it into an xsl file with the same error. I'll probably look into another gem file since Roo isn't working properly at the moment. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Open Office may be able to read and save to xlsx in a way that Excel would understand it but Roo may not. I would submit this information to the Roo developers or at the very least check their issue tracker to see if anyone else has issues with Excel formats exported from Open Office.

Comment: Thanks Chris, I will continue researching!